# Как отсортировать массив строк по своей сортировке?

Tags: массивы, delphi

Как можно отсортировать массив строк, если есть массив, где по порядку соблюдена сортировка такая, как мне нужна. В моем случае это:

1. Т-90
2. Т-100
3. Т-110
4. Т-120
5. Тв
6. Без анализа
7. Не стандартная
8. Бракованая

И есть свой массив, который мне нужно отсортировать по списку выше. Как это сделать?

Comment: можно по подробнее с примером что еимеем и что нада на выходе получить) небольшой кусочек приведите плиз

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что: 

 - У вас есть некий список строк/массивов/кортежей/объектов, который вы хотите отсортировать. 
 - Объекты в вашем списке в качестве одного из своих полей/элементов содержат строку.
 - Эта строка может принимать одно из 8 значений описанных в вопросе.
 - Ваш список вы хотите отсортировать по этому строковому значению, в соответствии с приоритетами возможных значений (сначала Т-90, потом Т-100 и так далее).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень схематично. Заведите функцию сравнения двух элементов A и B, которая бы:

1. искала бы положение A в эталонном массиве (a)
2. искала бы положение B в эталонном массиве (b)
3. возвращала бы (a-b), то есть >0 если A "больше" B, 0 если A "равно" B, <0 если A "меньше" B

Ну и дальше пользуйтесь этой функцией как вспомогательной для QuickSort, например. Со случаями, когда A или B не находятся в эталонном массиве, или есть частичное совпадение, или что-то ещё - разбирайтесь самостоятельно :)

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что приходит на ум:
если данные берутся из БД , то ввести дополнительные поля для сортировки.
В любом случае, должен быть признак, по которому сортируется.

Answer (score 0):

Эм..

я даже не знаю как вот это может отсортироваться

```
Тв
Без анализа
Не стандартная
Брако
```

Первая Тв, потом Б, потом Н, потом опять Б...